# Instagram callback URL subscription not working

Tags: python, api, instagram, subscription

Hello everyone im trying to subscribe to the Instagram API, but for some reason i keep on getting an error.

**code:**

```
# Subscribe to all media in a geographic area
api.create_subscription(object='geography', lat=35.657872, lng=139.70232, radius=1000, aspect='media', callback_url='http://locallhost.com/')
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner.Owner-PC/Documents/Final Year Project/testing.py", line 26, in <module>
    api.create_subscription(object='geography', lat=35.657872, lng=139.70232, radius=1000, aspect='media', callback_url='http://locallhost.com/')
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\instagram\bind.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\instagram\bind.py", line 189, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\instagram\bind.py", line 123, in _do_api_request
    signature = hmac.new(secret, ips, sha256).hexdigest()
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\hmac.py", line 144, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\hmac.py", line 42, in __init__
    raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__)
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
```

Now i am very confused what the error is, can someone please explain how to solve this?

Comment: What version of python-instagram?

Comment: How do i check? also does it matter what version?